# How could I move/offset the sequence in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

so let's say I have these things in the first column:

apple
banana
cherry
socks

If I put "TRUE" in column B next to any of them, the numbering should start from that position. when it reaches the end (so colmn A has no value), it must go to the start and continue the numbering there.

This sounds complicated and stupid, so for example

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 1 | TRUE |
| banana | 2 |  |
| cherry | 3 |  |
| socks | 4 |  |

if I put "TUE" in the 3rd row, then:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 3 |  |
| banana | 4 |  |
| cherry | 1 | TRUE |
| socks | 2 |  |

Is this even possible to achieve? If so, how? I've been doing research on this problem and found nothing, but dozens of explanations of "SEQUENCE" (which does not resolve the issue).

Comment: write a loop to find the start and end of the table (or use `getDataRange`); write a loop to find "TRUE". Write a loop going from i = `PositionOfTrue` To `EndOfTable`, set column B from 1 to `Whatever`. Then do a loop from i = `firstRow` to `PositionOfTrue - 1` and set Column B = `whatever + i` - Maybe I'll write a more detailed answer later, but right now I'm on my way home from work. `Whatever is basically the variable keeping track on which iteration of the loop you are on (don't use let (if declared in the loop), you need the variable to be scoped so both loops access the same one)

Comment: I have solution to this problem, but it will take time to build and test it, if you want the solution, we need to discuss further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution:

```
=LET(a,MATCH(TRUE,B:B),b,COUNTA(A:A)-a+1,TOCOL({SEQUENCE(a-1,1,b+1);SEQUENCE(b)},3))
```

[image]

Comment: okay so this is a different problem, but how can you use " , " marks instead of " ; " marks? If I try to use " , " it breaks. Is there a setting I'm missing? I've seen Many people use it like that. Edit: Oh I see, it changes based on the set location.. wow. https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/sheets-location/

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=let(Σ,xmatch(TRUE,B:B),Λ,index(match(,0/(A:A<>""))),Γ,index(match(,0/(index(A:A,Σ):index(A:A,Λ)<>""))),
       tocol({sequence(Λ-Γ,1,Γ+1,1);sequence(Γ)},3))
```

- desgined/tested for single `TRUE` statement in `Column_B`; aint sure if there's goin' to be multiple ones or so...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Here's my take on the problem!](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pvOuHUHdB0InER8Os4yGM5b9NsV4H2S3RDiUYQ2pbaQ/edit?usp=sharing) I've added rockinfreakshow and ztiaa's answers as well. I opted for a slightly different approach, as I thought it would be more interesting. It's also slightly shorter!
`=sortn(row(A:A),counta(A:A),,sort(scan(,B:B,lambda(a,b,a+b)),A:A="",1,row(A:A),),1)`